# Adding values to Combobox dynamically in jsp

Tags: jsp

how can i Add  database values to my combox() on selected index changed event of another combobox in the same jsp page
please help fast..............

here is my code

```
<tr>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="cboItems" id="cboItems">
                            <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
                            <%
                                CommodityInfoActions comObj = new CommodityInfoActions(erpConn);
                                comObj.getAllRecords();
                                Iterator itr = comObj.ListOfObjects.iterator();
                                int i = 1;
                                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                                    CommodityInfo newObj = (CommodityInfo) itr.next();
                                    String item = newObj.getCommodityName();
                                    long itemid = newObj.getId();
                                    out.println("<option value='" + itemid + "' >" + item + "</option>");
                                    i++;
                                }

                            %>
                        </select>                                
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Batch No. </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="cboBatchNo">
                            <option>--select--</option>
                            <%
                                try {
                                    if (Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("cboItems")) > -1) {
                                        CommodityPriceActions comp = new CommodityPriceActions(erpConn);
                                        comp.getBatchno(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("cboItems")));
                                        CommodityPrices comPrice = new CommodityPrices();
                                        itr = comp.ListOfObjects.iterator();
                                        i = 1;
                                        while (itr.hasNext()) {
                                            CommodityPrices newObj = (CommodityPrices) itr.next();

                                            out.println("<option value='" + newObj.getId() + "'>" + newObj.getBatchNo() + "</option>");
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception exc) {
                                }
                            %>

                        </select>
                    </td>                        
                </tr>
```

i want ot change the content of  cboBatchno according to the option selected in cboItems at runtime...

Comment: You can add onchange event to combobox1 and send the request via ajax and populate the success data from ajax into combobox2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ddMyth2857356 I don know really what you tried? Here is the hint,

```
$('#combobox1').change(function(){
var id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
    url : "servlet_URL&id="+ id,
    type : "POST",
    success : function(data) {
        $("#combobox2").html(data);
    }
});
});
```

This is one of the idea. You come up with what you tried and what issues you are facing? Hope this helps.

Comment: can u help  me  with the data part that u have specified.

Comment: @ddMyth2857356 You can receive the id in servlet by `requset.getparameter("id")` and use the value for querying the table. Finally use jsp page to compose your data like `<option value="">your value</option>`. Then your jquery ajax will take care of filling the second combobox.